# rxjs and angular router events: Set boolean to inital value after first emit

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-router-events

this function below should return true if an angular router event was triggered.

```
private routeChanged$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        mapTo(true),
        startWith(false),
        untilDestroyed(this)
    );
}
```

it works fine but it should also reset again the inital value (false) after the event was fired so
i basically want to set the boolean back to false after it emits true the first time (when the route changed)
(sorry for my bad english, i hope you get my point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean it should immediately emit `false` again after `true`?

In that case you could do:

```
private routeChanged$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        switchMapTo([true, false]),
        startWith(false),
        untilDestroyed(this)
    );
}
```

`switchMapTo` will "subscribe" to the array - which is interpreted as an Observable emitting two values, true and false.